# Can't rebind caret and tilde in DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Tags: keybindings

I have an extensive `DefaultKeyBinding.Dict` file that mostly works very well for me.  I use Karabiner Elements to change the behavior of the right-alt so that it sends `§`, which signals the beginning of a compose sequence, and then the keybinding table takes over. My `DefaultKeyBinding.Dict` starts like this:

```
{"§" = {
  "g" = {
    "h" = ("insertText:", "ȝ");
    "," = ("insertText:", "ģ");
    "." = ("insertText:", "ġ");
    "(" = ("insertText:", "ğ");
    "U" = ("insertText:", "ğ");
    …
```

These bindings all work as expected.  For example, right-alt `g` `h` produces `ȝ` and right-alt `g` `.` produces `ġ`.

But none of my sequences that involves `^` or `~` is working.  I know these symbols have a special meaning in the `DefaultKeyBinding.Dict` syntax, but none of [the escape sequences for them](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html) is working either.  For example, I am supposed to be able to use `\136` (octal) or `\U005E` to represent the caret `^`, but keybindings involving this character never work.  I've tried inserting each of the following in the same block as the bindings above, then typing right-alt `g` `^`:

```
    "\U005e" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");  // ^
    "\U005E" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");  // ^
    "\^" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");      // ^
    "\136" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");    // ^

    // These are not supposed to work but I tried them anyway
    "\x5e" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");    // §g^
    "\0136" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");   // §g^

    // Different strategy
    "$6" = ("insertText:", "yobgorgle");      // §g^
```

None of these has produced `yobgorgle`; all the advertised syntax has produced a plain `^` symbol.  If they were being completely ignored, they would produce `§g^` like the bottom three, so *something* is happening, but I don't understand what.

I don't understand why `"$6"` didn't work either, that is supposed to mean shift-6, which is where my caret symbol is.

The sequence `\033` for the "esc" key *does* work as advertised.

I am using `iTerm2` to test the binding changes.  I have not forgotten that I need to kill and restart the app to get it to notice the new keybindings.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

(The following was tested on macOS 13.5.)

The caret (^) can be escaped with `\\^`.

The tilde (~) can be escaped with `\\~`.

For example, with the following contents of DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{"§" = {
  "i" = {
    "\\^" = ("insertText:", "î");
  };
};}
```

Typing the sequence `§ i ^` will produce the character î.

#### Why other escape sequences don't work

In my testing, escape sequences such as `\136` and `\U005E` didn't work because they were first translated to `^` before being parsed as a key binding, resulting in identical behaviour to just specifying `^`.

Your alternate method `$6` didn't work because key bindings are case-sensitive (Shift-sensitive?), and it is not possible to type "6" while the Shift key is held down. You can verify this behaviour by attempting to create a key binding with `$b`, which doesn't work (because lowercase b cannot be typed while holding Shift), versus `$B`, which does.

#### What is the unescaped behaviour?

The unescaped character `^` means that the Control key is held down. If you don't specify anything after the ^, then the text system will accept *any* input while the control key is held down as a match.

For example, with the following contents of DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{"§" = {
  "i" = {
    "^" = ("insertText:", "î");
  };
};}
```

Typing the sequence `§ i Ctrl+B` will produce the character î.
But so will `§ i Ctrl+Option+W`, `§ i Ctrl+Shift+LeftArrow`, or any other key combination as long as Ctrl is held down.

The same goes for when the unescaped character `~` is specified in a key binding by itself, but in that case it's any key combination with the Option key held down.

#### macOS built-in utility for key remapping

This wasn't part of your question, but you may be interested in `hidutil`, described at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html.

You can use the following command to remap the right-Option key to § without using any third-party software:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000E6,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000064}]}'
```

The above does not persist across reboots, so you'll need a way to automatically re-run it at startup. You can do so using a launchd agent. Save the following as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.RemapRightOptionToNonUsBackslash.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.RemapRightOptionToNonUsBackslash</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/hidutil</string>
        <string>property</string>
        <string>--set</string>
        <string>{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000E6,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000064}]}</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```